# Formatting and comparing arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format, compare

I am trying to check if the formatted vector `a_and_b[::2]` is equivalent to `a`, but it is giving me an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. How would I be able to fix that and get the Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([5,32,1,4])
b = np.array([1,5,11,3])
a_and_b = np.array([5,1,32,5,1,11,4,3])
result = 'yes'  if a_and_b[::2] == a else 'no'
```

Expoected output:

```
yes
```

Comment: look at `a_and_b[::2] == a ` before trying to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use this:

```
(a_and_b[::2] == a).all()
```

which will return `True` if all of the elements of each array are equal, since:

```
>>> a_and_b[::2] == a
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

returns an array of `True`/`False`. `all()` will indicate whether all the elements of that array are `True` or not.

So try:

```
result = 'yes' if (a_and_b[::2] == a).all() else 'no'
```